# recursively create a nested object from other object in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested-object

I'm new to programming, and I was working a question which is bother me for a while.

I want to recursively create a nested object from another nested object in javascript,

below is the sample data for input, but in real situation, I don't how deep will this object to be.

```
nums = {
    Obj:{
        x1:{
            x11:43,
            x12:4,
            x13:612
        },
        x2:{
            x21:4,
            x22:7,
        },
        x3:2,
    }}
```

this is the result I want (see number is even or odd, even=true, odd=false)

```
res = {
    Obj:{
        x1:{
            x11:false,
            x12:true,
            x13:true
        },
        x2:{
            x21:true,
            x22:false,
        },
        x3:true,
    }}
```

and this is my code

```
const nums = {
    Obj:{
        x1:{
            x11:43,
            x12:4,
            x13:612
        },
        x2:{
            x21:4,
            x22:7,
        },
        x3:2,
    }
}
const res ={};

getResult(nums);

console.log(res);

function getResult(x){
    Object.keys(x).forEach(element => {
        if(isNaN(x[element])){
            res[element]=getResult(x[element]);
        } else {
            let result = (x[element] % 2 < 1)? true:false;
            return {[element]: result}; // this is where I don't know what to, I try to return a object, 
                                        //  but it gives{x1: undefined, x2: undefined, Obj: undefined}
                                        //
                                        // if I change to "return res[element]=result"
                                        // every sub-Object will add under the same level
        }
    });
}
```

I will really appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `return {[element]: result};` , overwrite the value, and return the mutated object from the function after the loop :

note that this will mutate the original object, if you want to keep it, make a copy :

`const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nums));`

```js
const nums = {
  Obj: {
    x1: {
      x11: 43,
      x12: 4,
      x13: 612
    },
    x2: {
      x21: 4,
      x22: 7,
    },
    x3: 2,
  }
}
const res = {};
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nums));

getResult(copy);

console.log(res);

function getResult(x) {
  Object.keys(x).forEach(element => {
    if (isNaN(x[element])) {
      res[element] = getResult(x[element]);
    } else {
      let result = (x[element] % 2 < 1) ? true : false;
      x[element] = result; // overwrite the number with true or flse
    }
  });
  return x; // return the mutated object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mutating something make something more functional and return a new object:

```
const getResults = o => typeof o === "object"
    ? Object.keys(o).reduce((a, k) => ({ ...a, [k]: getResults(o[k]) }), {})
    : o % 2 === 1;
```

Basically we check if object is an object (using typeof) and go deeper if so. Otherwise we check if it is odd or even.

Answer (score 1):

You can also think of this more generically, writing a function that will apply your transformation to all the leaf nodes of your object, then calling it with an `isEven` function.  Here's one technique:

```js
const mapLeaves = (fn) => (tree) =>
  typeof tree == "object"
    ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (tree) .map (
        ([k, v]) => [k, mapLeaves (fn) (v)]
      ))
    : fn (tree)
 
const isEven = (n) => n % 2 == 0

const nums = {Obj: {x1: {x11: 43, x12: 4, x13: 612}, x2: {x21: 4, x22: 7}, x3: 2}}

console .log (
  mapLeaves (isEven) (nums)
)
```

And of course `mapLeaves (isEven)` is a reusable function that you could apply to multiple objects.

This does not handle arrays.  It would only be slightly more complex to create a version of `mapLeaves` that also applied this to entries of an array:

```js
const mapLeaves = (fn) => (tree) =>
  Array .isArray (tree)
    ? tree .map (x => mapLeaves (fn) (x))
  : typeof tree == "object"
    ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (tree) .map (
        ([k, v]) => [k, mapLeaves (fn) (v)]
      ))
  : fn (tree)
```